# Is there a general name for this sort of cryptographic protocol?

Tags: cryptography

Is there a general name for this sort of cryptographic protocol?

If so what sort of assymetric/symmetric encryption functions tend to be used for this protocol?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's no such thing as a symmetric key *pair*.

Comment: Why can't I use the word pair to refer to two items?

Comment: 'Cause they are one item...

Comment: They are identical copies of each other, not one item.

Comment: The correct term is "shared key" or "shared secret". A key pair implies one complements the other. A shared secret implies that the same value is shared by more than one party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing can be referred to as a [hybrid cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) where asymmetric ciphers like RSA is used to exchange encryption keys that will then be used with symmetric ciphers like AES.

The main problem with the method you describe is that the client is requesting the public key from the *server* which can be replaced by an attacker that is sitting between them performing a [MITM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attack. This can be overcomed with something like the x509 CA system, which brings you to a system known as [PKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure). This is the backbone of SSL/TLS.

Comment: Yes I was going to ask about this, what if someone was to watch for clients requesting a public key from the server. Then send a non authentic key to the clients using a spoofed source ip address belonging to the server. Then with this non authentic public key, the attacker could pretend to be the server and unencrypt any data sent to him from the client with his private key.

Comment: @user45218 With that, you're essentially describing an MiTM attack, which is what the whole PKI thing is designed to prevent.